# Print the Moving text Every 5 Seconds in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i Need To Print the text which is moving for every 5 seconds,the html code is attacched below:

**HTML :**

```
<span class="cd-words-wrapper" style="width: 1170px;">
    <b class="is-hidden">Test</b>
    <b class="is-hidden">Test</b>
    <b class="is-visible">Test</b>
    <b class="is-hidden">Test</b>
</span>
```

My Python code:

```
 Text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(self.header)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(Text.text)
```

The Above is the Wrong way of Getting the Text. Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: What do you mean by *"moving"*?

Comment: 'Moving' Means like first one text will appear then another, Like a Slide wave, it is not static @Andersson

Comment: Do you mean that each 5 seconds text appears (become visible) in different `b` node?

Comment: Excatly! @Andersson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print text once it appear in new `b`node, try below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

while True:
    text_node = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cd-words-wrapper > .is-visible')))
    print(text_node.text)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: text_node.get_attribute('class') == "is-hidden")
```

If you want just to print all text nodes:

```
for text_node in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.cd-words-wrapper > b'):
    print(text_node.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: Awesome way of getting text! As am new to python i think i need more to learn.!